# How can I determine if a user has included a time in a single input/string?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time

I'm asking the user to type a meeting description in one field. I'd like to intelligently guess/parse when a user includes a time in this input, to save them from having to fill out a separate time input field.

Google Calendar uses this kind of parsing to pre-fill time fields.

Example inputs:

- *Meet at Burger King at 2:30* - I want to pull out "2:30" and convert it to a date/time
- *Denny's 2pm* - I want to pull out "2pm"
- *1 at McDonald's* - I want to pull out "1"

I'd be grateful for any help!

Comment: http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: the singe digit would be the hardest to intelligently determine. The rest you can do all kinds of regex to parse/check format.

Comment: I would personally do this with a regular expression.

Comment: the datejs thing is also cool.. but like I said, the 1 digit stuff is hard to get... You could write "i want to be there at 1" and it will not detect anything. Because you could also write "I want to buy 2 phones"....

Comment: if the single digit is always followed/preceeded by "at" then that makes it easier

Answer (score 0):

I know you are asking for a JS solution, but I wrote some code in PHP that you might want to check and see if the logic helps you with your project.

```
<?php
$string1 = "Meet at Burger King at 2:30";
$string2 = "Denny's 2pm";
$string3 = "I want to buy 2 phones at 1";

print iterateString($string1).  "- It should return 2:30<br>";
print iterateString($string2). "- It should return 2pm<br>";
print iterateString($string3). "- It should return 1:00<br>";

function isTime($date, $formats=array("H:i","G:i","Ha","ha", "Ga", "ga")) {
    foreach($formats as $format) {
        $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
        $fd = $d ? $d->format($format) : false;

        if ($d && $fd == $date) {
            return $fd;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function iterateString($string) {
    $singleTime = false;
    $words =  explode(" ",$string);
    foreach($words as $word) {
        if ($singleTime && ctype_digit($word)) {
            $word = $word . ":00";
        }

        if($time = isTime($word)) {
            return $time;
        }

        if($word == 'at') {
            $singleTime = true;
        } else {
            $singleTime = false;
        }
    }
    return "error";
}
```